# How to fix npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed error?

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I try to create a react application using  `npx create-react-app .`,I get this error. How do I solve this?

````
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2ftype-utils reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2ftype-utils: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sarang Dutta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-18T17_45_33_992Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.```
````